# MySQLdb is error in making a Primary key which is too long

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am creating a table in using MYSQLdb in Python

```
tdesc  = "CREATE TABLE " + self.table_name + " ("
        tdesc  = tdesc + "title VARCHAR(500), "
        tdesc  = tdesc + "DbLink VARCHAR(500), "
        tdesc  = tdesc + "abstract VARCHAR(3000), "
        tdesc  = tdesc + "WikiLink VARCHAR(5000),"
        tdesc  = tdesc + "PRIMARY KEY (DbLink)"
        tdesc  = tdesc + ")"
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor ()
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')

yes my key is a bit long string. Could some one guide me how shall I deal with this key issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without telling us what that DBLink column is supposed to do it is kind of hard to solve this ...

Your key is too long, there are no two ways about it. You can do two things, either you make the DBLink column smaller. Or, alternatively, you could create a new primary key, say an auto-incremented id, and add a unique constraint to your DBLink column.

Comment: what is and auto-incremented id?        dbLink is a url of a page for example : "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Madigan%27s_Millions"

Comment: If I follow your approach and try to make dbLink as Unqiue, Mysql still ask me that size is bigger then maximum lenght

Answer (score 0):

Primary key in MySQL is a longint. Do not use value longest that this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auto increasing id value for the string field that you want to assign as a primary key. Also this will help you by creating a better index on primary key if you want it.